# WooCommerce - Add Link Attribute to product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an attribute created called "Vendor". I would like to add that attribute either after the product title or in the product meta section on the product page that is linked to the archive pages for that attribute (similar to this shop: https://www.luckyvitamin.com/p-320978-newman-s-own-organics-pop-s-corn-organic-microwave-popcorn-butter-3-pop-serve-bags-3-3-oz).

A sample product page is located here: https://graysmarketplace.com/product/organic-valley-organic-large-brown-eggs-1-dozen/

I am pretty familiar with the structure of WooCommerce code and hooks, but I can't figure out how to get what I want.

Comment: External links are doomed to rot in short order. Try to make this question stand-alone by describing what you want, what you have tried, and what problem you encountered.

Comment: In WooCommerce there is no archive pages for attributes. Archives pages exists only for shop, for product categories and product tags.